# What is this meme from "Stewie joins a football team"?

Tags: family-guy

In a Family Guy episode, which I think "Stewie joins a football team" there is a montage where Peter is doing ride-a-longs with Joe and at one point they have a clip with Peter's face superimposed on one of the actors. Basically what happens is that the woman lets the guy in the wheelchair (which is a dummy) go down the stairs.

Is this clip some kind of meme?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a clip from the movie *The Naked Gun: From the Files of Police Squad*.

In this case Peter's been put over Detective Frank Drebin (Leslie Nielsen) who is talking with Jane Spencer (Priscilla Presley) who is giving him details of her boss's evil plot.  In the wheelchair is superimposed Joe Swanson as Frank's partner and friend Nordberg (OJ Simpson) , who gets injured badly at the start of the movie.

The connection is the police angle, but there's no real "meme" so far as I can tell...